# Second order differential equation not getting solved using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve this second order differential equation
$-\frac{k T}{q n(x)} \frac{d^2n(x)}{dx^2} + \frac{k T}{q (n(x))^2} (\frac{d n(x)}{dx})^2 = \frac{q}{\epsilon} (N_D(x) - n(x))$. 
So I want to solve for $n(x)$ in terms of $N_D(x)$ where rest of the variables are physical units which we can leave as it is.

```
DSolve[(-k*T )/(q y[x])*y''[x] + (k*T)/(q*(y[x])^2)*(y'[x])^2 == 
  q/\[Epsilon]*(y0 - y[x]), y[x], x]
```

I tried doing this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it. What initial conditions would be required? You can assume trivial conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. See if  you can experiment and find any initial condition that doesn't give an empty solution and warning: `Assuming[k>0&&T>0&&\[Epsilon]>0&&q>0,DSolve[{-k*T/(q y[x])*y''[x]+k*T/(q*y[x]^2)*y'[x]^2==q/\[Epsilon]*(y0 - y[x]),y[1]==1},y[x],x]]`

Comment: Thanks, I just want to find out closed form expression of y[x] in terms of y0 (which is also a function of x) and see how different is y[x] from y0

Comment: I can tell that y0[0] = 1, so we can probably assume y[0] = 1. [Because from the physics of the problem, y[x]~y0[x], so by solving this differential equation, I wanted to check how far is y[x] from y0[x]. Is there any other way of solving differential equations in mathematica?

Comment: This is a nonlinear equation. $n(x)$ can be arbitrarily far from $N_D(x)$. It all depends on the initial conditions. Therefore, it is necessary to determine all parameters and function $N_D(x)$. And investigate the solution depending on the initial data using `NDSolve[]`

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there is a closed-form solution?  IMO, the default assumption when one encounters a non-linear ODE is that it doesn't have a closed-form solution.

Comment: Also, note that substituting $w = \ln n$ yields the ODE$$-\frac{kT}{q} \frac{d^2 w}{dx^2} = \frac{q}{\epsilon} (N_D(x) - e^{w(x)})$$which is, at least, nicer-looking.  It can also be partially integrated when $N_D$ is a constant, at least, and may also be integrable for certain values of the initial conditions.

Comment: Thanks. How do I solve this for constant $N_D$?

Comment: From the physics of the problem I think it is reasonable to assume $n(\infty)= 0$ and $n'(\infty)= 0$.